# Makefile with OpenSSL LDLIBS flag enabled giving error

Tags: c, makefile, openssl

I am able to run and compile my c example program with openssl using

```
gcc azureconn.c -o azureconn -lssl -lcrypto
```

but when I try to compile using makefile with LDLIBS flag in make file, it result into error as undefined reference OPENSSL_Init
Below is my make file

```
    DEFINES = $(GDEFINES)

INCLUDES = $(DIR_PATH)

CFLAGS = $(GCFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) -D_GNU_SOURCE
LDLIBS = -lssl -lcrypto


MAIN_OBJECTS = xxxx.o yyy.o zzz.o \
aaaa.o 


all: $(MAIN_OBJECTS) 

    mv $(MAIN_OBJECTS) $(BIN_PATH)

%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

clean: 
    rm -rf *.o
```

Error

> undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl' collect2: error: ld returned
>   1 exit status

Comment: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I don't see `azureconn.c` mentioned anywhere in your makefile

Comment: Sorry azureconn.c was rename as t5ais.o

Answer (score 0):

Since you've changed your question.  Which module has the `main(...)` function in it?  I assumed it was azureconn.c since you said you can compile with this.

```
gcc azureconn.c -o azureconn -lssl -lcrypto
```

Try using a rule like this to build your executable;

```
azureconn: 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) azureconn.c -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
```

The `%.o:%.c` rule is not typically used to link, just create object files as the name implies

Comment: your and my rule are same

Comment: @ParthDesai having `-c` in the command line says don't link, just compile.

Comment: I want to create object file as well in my case

Comment: But for example I have taken azureconn but In real scenario I have multiple files

Comment: If I remove -c it gives another error as /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib32/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'

Comment: I have main in xxx.c file whereas I want to link to azureconn.c which doesnt contain main. So In this case if i go with xxx then i will get undefined reference error